# Cordova freezing on building/adding platform

Tags: android, cordova, cmd

I use the command "Cordova create testApp com.example.testApp AppletTest" and this creates the folder where all the subfolders live. The next stage is to build and add a platform. When I try to add the android platform it doesn't crash but doesn't seem to do anything.

I used the add platform command with a -d on the end to see what was going on and it looks like it's just trying to run the .bat file and waits there.

I've re-installed Cordova, made sure my SDK was upto date, set environment variables and now i'm stumped.

Please note.. I can add a platform for WP8 and that seems to load fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm going to go through the process on my other pc to see if this problem persists.

Thanks in advance.
Josh

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this myself guys, I was an idiot and overwritten a load of system and other environment variables by setting the "Android_Home" system variable.